# I have a linux subsystem installed with Debian but I need to know how to link it to the rest of my computer

Tags: python, pip, debian

So I used Debian to install a Linux subsystem so I could use pip with it because it for some reason pip wouldn't work if I tried using it with my cmd prompt. I tried to reach a file directory in my computer with it, and it doesn't work. Is there a way I can link the subsystem to the rest of my computer?

Comment: Your question is not that much clear, if you are using Debian, both python 3.x and 2.x comes preinstalled, so you should be able to access pip directly

Comment: what is it a "Linux subsystem"? BTW you should go to out "Unix & Linux" sister site: it is the relevant site for such questions (but please: write it much more clear, add example of what you did, and the error you get). [You can access the sister sites on top banner, right button]